# .htaccess particular query redirect?

Tags: joomla-2.5, .htaccess-configuration

I've got a Joomla 2.5 website and a phpbb forum together.
I wanted to redirect the registration of the Joomla Website to the registration to my forum.

My current registration link (in joomla 2.5) is:

```
mywebsite.com/component/users/?view=registration
```

I want to redirect it to:

```
mywebsite.com/forum/ (or "mywebsite.com/forum" ,without the final slash)
```

I tried traditional methods and they did no work, I also tried query redirect but everything I found on the web was about redirecting a query like this:

```
mywebsite.com/something?query=somethingelse
```

but in this particular case, the query is after the "/" so it's not working.

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a plugin for login\user integration?

A google search gave me this plugin that might work: http://www.jfusion.org/feature/jfusion-features. It's supposed to create a complete integration, combining your Joomla users with your PHPBB users.

Other than that, can't you just change the registration link to `example.com/forum`? If it's the link in the loginform, you can create an override for `mod_login` by copying `ROOT/modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php` to `ROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/mod_login/default.php`, then edit at about line 100:

```
<?php if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration')) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="http://example.com/forum">
        <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_REGISTER'); ?> <span class="icon-arrow-right"></span></a>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ttried it out myelsf, but this code should work. Remeber to to write conditions in the .htaccess after the "RewriteEngine on" rule

```
rewriterule ^component/users/?view=registration(.*)$ http://example.com/forummywebsite.com/forum/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: No, it didn't work. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this query redirect (i use this one for my query redirects in Joomla):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} view=registration
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mywebsite.com/forum/? [R=301,L]
```

cheers!